# Restrict Firestore and Realtime Database write access

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I want to restrict writing permissions on both Firestore and Realtime Database so that only app's backend can modify it.

What kind of rules can I apply? 
It seems that Database Secrets are not safe to use now.

Answer (score 1):

It depends a bit how your backend process accesses the databases.

If they do so through a Firebase Admin SDK, they will be accessing the database with administrative privileges and thus bypass all security rules. That means you can just lock down writes on the database completely for all regular clients.

In the Realtime Database, that can be accomplished with these rules:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".write": false
  }
}
```

In Cloud Firestore, you accomplish the same with:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow write: if false;
    }
  }
}
```

In both cases I've ignore read permissions to keep things simple. The above snippets are fairly directly lifted from the Firebase documentation, so I'd recommend reading more about [Realtime Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/quickstart) and [Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started) there.